# What does "Select your next badge" popup look like when you have got all badges?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I wonder what the "Select your next badge" popup looks like when you've got all the badges listed there...

Comment: I'll be disappointed if it isn't something like "**CONGRATULATIONS!!!**" with fireworks.

Comment: I would like to see a dancing unicorn, but most likely it will just be empty. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard [feature-request]

Answer (score 13):

It will be empty. See the user profile of the user [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef?tab=badges&sort=class) on Stack Overflow. (S)he is most likely the only such user on the network, since I checked all users with the Illuminator badge (this might be outdated).
The honourable mention goes to [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe?tab=badges&sort=class), who only needs the Peer Pressure badge, which is very hard to get if you only post good answers.

Of course, we do not know for certain whether they don't see a dancing unicorn.

I also think it is disappointing that the Socratic counter doesn't show, say, 143/200, since you can earn the Socratic badge multiple times and it normally shows up in the next badge section.

Comment: With that, I think the gear also be absent.

Comment: Maybe we should ask them in chat to figure out what the user see?

Comment: @nicael [go ahead](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef). ;)

Comment: Note that there are multiple badges that are trackable and that you can get more than once, although Socratic is probably the most illustrious by some margin.

Comment: Your first link shows Next badge `Educated`, which is odd because that doesn't exist.

Comment: "the only such user on the network" - wow, that's quite an achievement!

Comment: @randal'thor It might be outdated by now, but I remember that most other users still needed either the Socratic, the Legendary or the Research Assistant badge. For Socratic you need to be an active asker, and most top users aren't. Also, Research Assistant is quite hard to get unless you specifically aim for it.