# On private beta sites the "Select your next badge" popup isn't populated from the "Track the next one" button, but works fine from "Let us pick"

Tags: bug, profile-page, private-beta, badge-progress, popups

On [private beta sites](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/current) (you need to be a member of "Proof Assistants" to access that URL), on the user profile activity page, when you earn a new badge there are two buttons presented: <kbd>Track the next one</kbd> and <kbd>Let us pick</kbd>:

[image: Badge Selector - "Track the next one" and "Let us pick"]

If you click on <kbd>Track the next one</kbd> the choice of next badge is completely blank, not even indicating the number of badges available (as in this [other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330156/282094)), instead it appears similar to [what you would see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272698/282094) when you've earned all your badges:

[image: "Select your next badge" popup, showing up completely blank]

You must choose <kbd>Let us pick</kbd>, that enables the "Next badge" cog, which then allows you to choose any available badge:

[image: "Next badge" Cog]

After clicking the cog the popup is correctly displayed, untill the next time; the *fix* is temporary.

[image: "Select the next badge" popup, correctly populated with available choices]

Bug: The site knows which badges you can earn and shows them correctly when you use the "Next badge" cog, but if you attempt to access that same popup using the "Track the next one" button the "Select your next badge" popup isn't populated with any badges or a count of the number remaining.

I've only observed this on private beta sites, on other sites I've not seen this bug.

Comment: I reported that bug already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375146/295232 - the beta site has no tag badges to track because there are no badges with 100 questions yet. I fear they [mixed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372633/2952320) tag badges and regular badges underwater ...

Comment: @Glorfindel, touché. I really did search. I get the difference between "tracking" and "choosing". A good signpost. Thanks for providing the duplicate.

Comment: One minor difference from [your situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375146/282094) is that you are offered tag badges instead of a blank popup; so the solution for this bug would be to remove the button altogether since it serves no purpose, it could be checked during the *0300 script* to determine when to enable it - or a message explaining that you can't track either regular or tag badges, the second because there isn't 100 questions.

Comment: VTR. As mentioned [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377181/track-the-next-one-window-shows-tag-badges-instead-of-normal-badges#comment1257405_377181) on a [new report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377181/track-the-next-one-window-shows-tag-badges-instead-of-normal-badges) on a similar if not identical matter, closing as a duplicate of a thread that received the bug report as an answer (among many others) is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Joachim However, as mentioned in the comments here, the bug is identical to that newer report, as this is in the specific case where no tag badges are issued on the site because no tag is being used on at least 100 questions (the dialog shown is the tag badge selection dialog). The duplicate target should have been changed to that one instead of this being reopened, since there's no use in having two questions reporting the same fundamental bug.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog It doesn't say they're identical anywhere - hence my initial comment - but Rob's second comment on the duplicate suggestion seems to suggest so, indeed. But this is the older question, so shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @Joachim The one that shows more research is the one that should be the canonical - that one points more clearly to the actual cause of the problem, which is that it's loading the tag badge dialog, while this one doesn't have that info needed for the team to debug it. Also, following the link to the answer to the announcement shows that that answer is the same as the linked bug report. Also, the 60-day statute of limitations for this unfairly counting negatively toward the author's question record has long expired, and as a result of the prior reopening this no longer counts as such.