# Empty "Select your next badge" window after validating a badge

Tags: bug, profile-page, badges, badge-progress

**SHORT DESCRIPTION**

The "Select your next badge" window of Stack Exchange presented after one has just validated a badge is empty.

**LONGER DESCRIPTION**

After receiving a new badge (in this case, "Enthusiast") with congratulations

> [image: Congratulations]

Selecting "Track the next one" opens a window where one should be able to choose the next badge to track on one's activity page.

I did so this morning, and the window shows an empty list:

> [image: Empty "Available" badges window]

And it is **not** because I already "got them all", all the lists displayed are empty:

> [image: Empty "All" badges window]

Selecting "let us pick" does work,

> [image: next Badge Student]

and then selecting "Next Badge" does open a window with full lists of available badges:

> [image: select your next badge]

It is very minor, and I assume that very few people would see its effect, but it seems like a bug nevertheless, so I thought I would take the time to report it here.

Have a good day, take care!

Comment: Is this the same bug? ["Track the next one" window shows tag badges instead of normal badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377181/track-the-next-one-window-shows-tag-badges-instead-of-normal-badges)

Comment: @ElementsInSpace Yes, it seems that it is the same as the particular case cited at the end of the question. Sorry if I created another duplicate!

Comment: Duplicate: ["Track the next one" window shows tag badges instead of normal badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377181/track-the-next-one-window-shows-tag-badges-instead-of-normal-badges)