# Incorrect tag badge interface

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badges, badge-progress

I just received the [Archaeologist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732) on Stack Overflow:

[image: Profile page showing congratulations for Archaeologist badge]

When I clicked **Track the next one**, I was displayed a choice of the **tag badges** I had made progress in instead:

[image: Tag badge modal]

Then when I clicked on the "Bronze" tab, I was displayed a tag badge I had already received (the Laravel bronze tag badge):

[image: Tag badge modal showing bronze tag badges]

I closed the modal, and clicked **Let us pick**. SO picked the [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399), and told me that my most recent (non-tag) badge was the Laravel tag badge.

[image: My badges in my profile showing the Laravel tag badge and progress to the Curious badge]

Clicking on the settings cog after this displayed the correct badge modal (i.e., the non-tag badges).

FWIW, [my most recent tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGx3K.png) in the Badges section of my SO profile is currently the Laravel bronze tag badge, the Archaeologist badge not having shown up there yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On private beta sites the "Select your next badge" popup isn't populated from the "Track the next one" button, but works fine from "Let us pick"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376787/282094) and (harder to find): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375146/282094